# Button border for button

Tags: android

This is my XML file for the border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

This is the XML file for the button

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/clearSelectionButton"
   android:layout_width="147dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/button_border"
   android:text="@string/clear_selection"
   android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: i think you forgot to ask question! What is your question ?

Comment: use android:backgroundTint="@null"

Answer (score 0):

If you just want border for a button, one way is to simply use Material OutlinedButton and specify stroke.

for example-

```
                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/standard_text"
                    app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```